# Linear Relationship of two equations

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

if 
$0.46a = 120b$
and
$2.68a = 60b$

The relationship is linear.

what does $0b$ equal in terms of $a$?

what does $1b$ equal in terms of $a$?

A method to work this out would also be nice, I have tied myself up in knots.
Many Thanks

Comment: Hi, since this is your first question here, I thought I'd point you to some useful links here. Take a look at [how to ask questions here in such a way to maximise your chances of getting them answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to format math here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, it's generally expected that you show what you've tried already.

Comment: Thank you, I finally worked out that using y= mx + c and changing the co-ordinates around you can find the y intercept. I could have looked harder but was getting very frustrated.